# How to fix Joomla (version > 3.6) administrator redirecting back to login page?

Tags: authentication, joomla, joomla3.0, administrator

When logging into Joomla! administrator, the user is redirected back to the login page. If the username/password are valid, no error messages. If the username/password are invalid, error messages to the effect.

The following is found in the Apache access log:

```
::1 - - [timestamp] "POST /localhost/administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 303 -
::1 - - [timestamp] "GET /localhost/administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6969
```

This is on the local copy of the site. It has not been touched since August 2018. The problem also occurs on the live site. Other Joomla! sites on localhost do work.

Have checked the `#__extensions` table and all necessary extensions are enabled. `com_login`, `com_users`, `plg_authentication_joomla`, `plg_authentication_cookie`, `plg_user_joomla`, etc.

Excerpts from config.php:

```
public $live_site = '';
public $cookie_domain = '';
public $cookie_path = '';
```

PHP `session.save_path` is server writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling Search Engine Friendly URLs and URL Rewriting  in Global Configuration / configuration.php i.e.:

```
public $sef = '1';
public $sef_rewrite = '1';
```

Try temporarily renaming `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` to see if this makes any difference.

Try clearing the Joomla cache, any server side cache (e.g. LiteSpeed Cache) and clearing your web browser cache.

You may also need to update the tmp and logs files paths in Global Configuration / configuration.php although this probably isn't causing the problem you are experiencing.

Another thing to try is a different PHP version.

Comment: Disabling SEF URLs had no effect. (The Administrator does not use SEF URLs.) Joomla! cache not used. All other caches either not present or empty. Local server is Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.28, MySQL 5.7. Valid paths for `tmp` and `logs`.

Comment: Does renaming .htaccess help?

Comment: Same as disabling SEF URLs. No effect.

Comment: Maybe try a different PHP version?

Comment: Live server, changed from `5.6.18-pl0-gentoo` to `7.0.2-pl0-gentoo` (server won't go any higher) (P.S. Joomla! 3.8.10). It works! Now I just have to upgrade the localhost. . . .

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. Please upvote if you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that happening could be upgrading to higher PHP version.
In my case it was happening when i upgraded PHP from 5.6 to 7.2. So the only solution i found was downgrading back to  PHP 5.6